# View-Based NSTableView does not display content of cells

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I try to display table based on data uploaded directly through the app. For this, I am using view-based NSTableView. Somehow in cells, "Table View Cell" is the only thing that displayed.

I checked previous questions but suggested solutions did not work for me. Also, there are no error messages at all.

Swift 5 is used, Cocoa app for MacOS.

```swift
import Cocoa
import CreateML
import Foundation

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var varsTable: NSTableView!

    var variables: [VarTypes] = []

    @IBAction func uploadButton(_ sender: Any) {
        let dialog = NSOpenPanel();

        dialog.title                   = "Choose a .csv file";
        dialog.showsResizeIndicator    = true;
        dialog.showsHiddenFiles        = false;
        dialog.canChooseDirectories    = true;
        dialog.canCreateDirectories    = true;
        dialog.allowsMultipleSelection = false;
        dialog.allowedFileTypes        = ["csv"];

        if (dialog.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK) {
            let result = dialog.url

            if let path = result?.absoluteURL {
                do {
                    let contents = try MLDataTable(contentsOf: path)

                    for i in 0..<contents.columnNames.count {
                        variables.append(VarTypes.init(varName: contents.columnTypes.map { $0.0 }[i], varType: String(describing: contents.columnTypes.map { $0.1 }[i])))
                    }

                    self.varsTable.reloadData()


                } catch {
                }
            } else {
                // the URL was bad!
            }
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        varsTable.delegate = self
        varsTable.dataSource = self
        self.varsTable.reloadData()
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {

    func numberOfRows(in varsTable: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return (variables.count)
    }

    func varsTable(_ varsTable: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        let varType = variables[row]

        guard let cell = varsTable.makeView(withIdentifier: tableColumn!.identifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else { return nil }

        if (tableColumn?.identifier)!.rawValue == "varName" {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = varType.varName
        } else {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = varType.varType
        }

        return cell
    }

}
```

This is how the storyboard [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yULOu.png) looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use Cocoa Bindings. It's very efficient and you get rid of a lot of code.

- Declare your model (please in singular form)

  ```
  @objcMembers
  class VarType: NSObject {

      dynamic var varName : String
      dynamic var varType : String
  }
  ```
- Declare the data source array

  ```
  @objc dynamic var variables: [VarType] = []
  ```
- Delete the entire `viewDidLoad()` method, the entire `extension ViewController` and all occurrences of `self.varsTable.reloadData()`

Now the Bindings part comes in.

- Go to Interface Builder and select the table view (not the scroll view!)
- Press <kbd>⌥⌘7</kbd> to select the Bindings Inspector
- Bind `Content` to `View Controller` *Model Key Path* `variables`

  [image]
- Select the `NSTextField` of the first column. Bind `Value` to `Table Cell View` *Model Key Path* `objectValue.varName`
- Select the `NSTextField` of the second column. Bind `Value` to `Table Cell View` *Model Key Path* `objectValue.varType`

Run the app.